# Database not updating? What's wrong with my code?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, sql-update

My database isn't updating.  I wanted the stock field of my book database to subtract by 1 whenever the user selects the borrow from a list and pushes the button.  When I check the database the stock field value doesn't change.

```
                newStock = stock - 1;
                try
                {
                    command.CommandText = "UPDATE Book SET [Stock] = @newStock WHERE [Title] = @title AND [Author]=@author";
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newStock", newStock);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", title);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author", author);
                    command.Connection = connect;
                    connect.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connect.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Done");
                    textBox1.Clear();
                    textBox2.Clear();
                }
                catch (OleDbException ex)
                {
                    connect.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
```

Comment: You really ought to consider properly naming your controls. It makes the code a lot more readable if the button is called `btnReturn`, rather than `Button1`

Comment: Yes, I plan to do that for programming ethics sake, but after the system is finished.

Comment: @JCBalantakbo There is no more lasting solutions than temporary solutions - just an observation. Also, remove everything not directly related to the problem (flags, useless empty event handlers, textBox updates...) from the question - create [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will be make the question much more clear and attractive to those who will try to answer, because it won't look like a code dump.

Comment: @JCBalantakbo There are many more things to remove from the code to make it MCVE. And all this windows forms stuff is irrelevant (at least in 99% cases) for your ADO.NET code and db interactions. Also, your title is nondescriptive and nonrelated to the problem you face - it just states that you have problem, not what this problem is. Make it something like "Update command does not update incremented value in the table". And about the problem: recheck it again whether you use correct values and the db is not updated for sure.

Comment: Do not remove too much. First select(where you get those values) is very relevant to the question, while `label4.Text` and error handling is not. Create small Console app with code that doesn't work and post it. This is the simplest way to create MCVE for small programs.

Comment: You don't show how stock is initialized. It could be that the problem lies before the above code executes. Did you try debugging to see what the values are for newStock and stock?